# When to use user defined class which extends RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception

I have create one user-defined  class (say `ClassA`) which extends `Exception`, and another class (`ClassB`) which extends `RuntimeException`. Please suggest me where I should use them in my application?

Should I use `ClassB` (which extend `RuntimeException`) in if statement like  if the account balance is low?

Comment: going through these questions may answer your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962310/user-defined-exceptions-when-do-we-use-them-what-is-an-exceptional-situation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612073/how-can-i-handle-user-defined-exceptions-and-after-handling-them-resume-the-flow

Answer (score 1):

An example of Runtime exception would be something that is thrown by the Runtime environment, like arithmetic or index out of bounds (the most common ones). Mostly these are technical in nature.

Business logic can be handled by extending the Exception class.

Comment: Would it be good practice of creating a Separate class(ClassB which extends RuntimeException in the project and use this like below            if(value==null){ throw new ClassB(Value Cannot be Null) }

Comment: in my mind those should be caught by enabling asertions in your development and check for assertions and disable them in production, especially for null values into method arguments. Yeach you could also do something like that as you suggested, but it is a good practice to catch these in development. Hence my recommendation for assertions.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb Joshua Bloch suggests is:

- use checked Exceptions (extend Exception) where you expect the application can recover from the exceptional state it came into
- use unchecked exception (extend RuntimeException) for scenarios where you don't expect possible recovery

Comment: Please suggest any real time example

Comment: This theme is exhausted :) I would suggest to see direct sublcasses of RuntimeException in javadoc and then use a good friend google. I even googled one nice for you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/index.html Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Standard exceptions are checked exceptions. So you need a try / catch block.
Runtime exceptions are unchecked exceptions that don't need a try / catch block. They shouldn't occur.

For your business logic like a low account balance you should probably use checked exceptions so that you have to handle them.